# Class and extension method container class in same namespace. What is the benefit?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nbuilder

I was trying [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/) in my unit test. An excellent library. However, I could not explain the following structure of classes and interfaces.

- In `FizzWare.NBuilder` namespace:

  - `ISingleObjectBuilder`
  - `SingleObjectBuilderExtensions`
- In `FizzWare.NBuilder.Implementation`

  - IObjectBuilder`
  - `ObjectBuilder`
- `SingleObjectBuilderExtensions` is simply a wrapper on `IObjectBuilder`.
- The client code should usually use a class named `Builder` which has a static method that gives you `ISingleObjectBuilder`. You never need to instantiate any of the classes in client code.

Now, I dont get the point of the `SingleObjectBuilderExtensions`. Does it give any kind of design benefit? Why not the methods are directly in `ISingleObjectBuilder` specially when the two interfaces are in same namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ISingleObjectBuilder` is an interface; interfaces cannot provide implementation. That would mean that every implementation of `ISingleObjectBuilder` would need to provide the implementation.

However, in many cases, a method has a pre-defined behaviour, and just needs access to other members of the interface (i.e. just members of `ISingleObjectBuilder`), so there is no benefit in making each implementation provide this.

Additionally, it is not a good idea to *add more members* to an existing interface, since that would be a breaking change for all existing implementations.

Extension methods solve both of these issues:

1. the extension method will work for all implementations of `ISingleObjectBuilder`
2. it doesn't change the existing API, so all existing implementations will continue to be valid

Having it in the same namespace simply makes it convenient. It is a likely bet that any code using `ISingleObjectBuilder` already has a `using` directive importing that namespace; therefore, most code will *already* see the extension method in the IDE simply by pressing `.` in the IDE.

To add a concrete example, LINQ-to-Objects works on `IEnumerable<T>`. There are **lots** of `IEnumerable<T>` implementations. If each of them had to write their own `First(...)`, `FirstOrDefault(...)`, `Any(...)`, `Select(...)` etc methods, that would be a *huge* burden - bot would provide no benefit as the implementations would be pretty much identical in most cases. Additionally, fitting this onto the interface retrospectively would have been disastrous.

As a side note: **per-type** versions of a method **always** take precedence over extension methods, so **if** (in the case of LINQ-to-Objects) you have a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` (for some `T`), and that type has a `.First()` instance method, then:

```
YourType foo = ...
var first = foo.First();
```

will use **your** version, not the extension methods.

Comment: The `LINQ-toObjects` analogy explains everything :) Thanks.

Comment: Mark, can you please check [**Extension method castin the first parameter to a sub-type. Is this good?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838949/extension-method-castin-the-first-parameter-to-a-sub-type-is-this-good)

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods are only syntactic sugar. They are normal static methods that work with public data the class they "extend" exposes.

There doesn't seem to be need for those extension methods to work with private fields and it also gives you ability to have interface instead of abstract class. And everyone knows interfaces are better choice than abstract classes.

And the reason for both to be in same namespace is to avoid declaring new namespace just to use the extension methods. How many times did it happen to you, that you tried to use LINQ only to notice there are no methods in intellisense or the code didn't compile. Reason being there was not System.Linq namespace included.