# Extension method casting the first parameter to a sub-type. Is this good?

Tags: c#, casting, extension-methods, nbuilder

I had another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823977/class-and-extension-method-container-class-in-same-namespace-what-is-the-benefi) in the same context. Now I have another query.

In [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/), `FizzWare.NBuilder` namespace contains the interface `ISingleObjectBuilder` and class `SingleObjectBuilderExtension` which is container of extension methods of `ISingleObjectBuilder`.

Now, the extension methods has a generic syntax:

```
public static ISingleObjectBuilder<T> ExMethod<T,[more types...]>(this ISingleObjectBuilder<T> objectBuilder, [more params])
{
    ((IObjectBuilder<T>)objectBuilder).ExMethod([more params]);
    return objectBuilder;
}
```

So you can see, although the methods accept `ISingleObjectBuilder`, it expects the parameter to be an `IObjectBuilder` which is a sub-interface of `ISingleObjectBuilder`.

Now consider this senario:

- I have implemented MySingleObjectBuilder:ISingleObjectBuilder.
- In my client code I have using `FizzWare.NBuilder` I can access `MySingleObjectBuilder.ExMethod()`
- When I do this, I obviously get an exception because `MySingleObjectBuilder` is not an `IObjectBuilder`.

Of course, it would be safer if the Extension Methods were for `IObjectBuilder`.
Now the question is, **isn't the safer option be better too?**

Comment: Call me silly, but most of the time - in my experience - if you're casting away an abstraction.. even to another abstraction, there's something smelly going on in your design..